# Remove an array element of an array object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state that contains an array of objects, and each object contains a `symbols` key with the array:

```
const [Symbols, setSymbols] = useState([{ symbols: [] }]);
```

Here is code:

```
const [Symbols, setSymbols] = useState([{ symbols: [] }]);

{Symbols.map((field, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
         {field.symbols.map((symbol, i) => {
            return (
              <div 
                key={i}
                onClick={() => {
                  const removeSymbol = CustomField.symbols.filter((_, index) => index !== i); 
                  return removeSymbol;
                }}
              >
                {symbol}
              </div>
            );
         })}
      </div>
    );
})}
```

And I want to remove the current symbol by clicking on that symbol. I tried this:

```
onClick={() => {
  const removeSymbol = CustomField.symbols.filter((_, index) => index !== i);
  return removeSymbol;
}}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear why you'd expect just returning an array from the handler callback to do _anything_. If you want to update the state you need  to call the function for updating the state: https://react.dev/learn/managing-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can see the problem is that you are not updateing the state using the `setSymbols` function also not triggering a re-render of the component.

```
const [Symbols, setSymbols] = useState([{ symbols: [] }]);

const handleSymbolClick = (fieldIndex, symbolIndex) => {
  const updatedSymbols = Symbols.map((field, i) => {
    if (i === fieldIndex) {
      const updatedField = { ...field };
      updatedField.symbols = field.symbols.filter((_, index) => index !== symbolIndex);
      return updatedField;
    }
    return field;
  });

  setSymbols(updatedSymbols);
};

{Symbols.map((field, fieldIndex) => {
  return (
    <div key={fieldIndex}>
      {field.symbols.map((symbol, symbolIndex) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={symbolIndex}
            onClick={() => handleSymbolClick(fieldIndex, symbolIndex)}
          >
            {symbol}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
})}
```